# Why is BERT model with pytorch native approach not learning?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

My custom BERT model's architecture:

```
class BertArticleClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_classes, freeze_bert_weights=False):
        super(BertArticleClassifier, self).__init__()

        self.bert = AutoModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

        if freeze_bert_weights:
            for param in self.bert.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.1)
        self.fc_1 = nn.Linear(768, 256)
        self.leaky_relu = nn.LeakyReLU()
        self.fc_out = nn.Linear(256, n_classes)

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
        output = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask)
        return self.fc_out(self.leaky_relu(self.fc_1(self.dropout(output['pooler_output']))))
```

`self.bert` is a model from transformers library.

Training script:

```
def train_my_model(model, optimizer, criterion, scheduler, epochs, dataloader_train, dataloader_validation, device, pretrained_weights=None):
    if pretrained_weights:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), pretrained_weights)

    for epoch in tqdm(range(1, epochs + 1)):
        model.train()
        loss_train_total = 0
        progress_bar = tqdm(dataloader_train, desc=f'Epoch {epoch :1d}', leave=False, disable=False)

        for batch in progress_bar:
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            batch = tuple(batch[b].to(device) for b in batch)
            input_ids, mask, labels = batch

            predictions = model(input_ids, mask)
            loss = criterion(predictions, labels)
            loss.backward()
            loss_train_total += loss.item()

            torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)

            optimizer.step()
            scheduler.step()

            progress_bar.set_postfix({'training_loss': '{:.3f}'.format(loss.item() / len(batch))})

        torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'models_data/bert_my_model/finetuned_BERT_epoch_{epoch}.model')
        tqdm.write(f'\nEpoch {epoch}')
        loss_train_avg = loss_train_total / len(dataloader_train)
        tqdm.write(f'Training loss: {loss_train_avg}')
        val_loss, predictions, true_vals = evaluate(model, dataloader_validation, criterion, device)
        val_f1 = f1_score_func(predictions, true_vals)
        tqdm.write(f'Validation loss: {val_loss}')
        tqdm.write(f'F1 Score (Weighted): {val_f1}')
```

Optimizer and Criterion:

```
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(),
                      lr=1e-4,
                      eps=1e-6)

class_weights = torch.tensor(class_weights, dtype=torch.float).to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights).to(device)
```

After 5 epochs I get the same validation loss ~3.1. I know that my data is preprocessed in the correct way because if I train this transformers `BertForSequenceClassification` model, the model is learning, but the problem with that approach is that I cannot tweak the loss function to accept the class weights, so that is the reason for creating my own custom model.

As you can see in the model's `forward` method, I extract the `output['pooler_output']` piece, and disregard the loss (which is returned alongside the `output['pooler_output']` element). The problem which I may deduced is that when in the training loop I call `loss.backward()`, maybe the model's weights aren't updating, because transformers BERT model's return their own loss as an output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi to my knowledge BertForSequenceClassification has almost the same implementation as yours, and they aren't using any custom losses, just the regular ```nn.CrossEntropyLoss()``` minus the class weights

Comment: You can see the code here
https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.html#BertForSequenceClassification

Comment: Another thing you can try to adjust is the learning rate and eps, BERT and its family use relatively lower learning rates: ```lr=2e-5, eps=1e-8```

Comment: With somebody's help I found one major issue, which is that I decrease my scheduler every batch, which is maybe the reason why my model doesn't learn.